# Reload HTML5 video with jquery that work on all browsers

Tags: safari, html5-video, reload

I am trying to reload a HTML5 video after I change the source `url` because I want to use a smaller file for mobile. The problem is I was trying the `.load();` command on the video tag. It worked great for all browsers but Safari. I heard that Safari doesn't support `.load();`.

Is there a better way to reload a video that works for all browsers?

Answer (score 0):

It seems strange that Safari's developer docs would [include examples](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/audiovideo/conceptual/using_html5_audio_video/controllingmediawithjavascript/controllingmediawithjavascript.html) that use .load() if it wasn't supported...

But anyway, you shouldn't need to call load() after setting the .src of the video. It's only needed if the  element has  elements inside it that you modify.

Comment: I found  I need a way to reset a playing video when I start a second video on the same page. I currently have them pause and return to 0 time. The problem I have been ask to make go back to poster image.